# To highlight difference between two images using asp.net web based application

Tags: asp.net

I have created simple demo for comparing two images. It compares two images & finds the difference between them & displays in third image using lockbits. But i want to highlight the difference between two images. How i can do this?
Asp.net c#
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to find the regions in the 2 images that differ and the probably draw a rectangle for those regions on those 2 images to show the difference. To detect the differ regions you can use various open source .net image analysis libraries like .NET port of OpenCV : http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page

Comment: May i know code for highlighting difference between two images correctly using opencv library